# Text in Spinner Becomes Faded After onCheckedChange From Radio Button

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner

What would cause the text to become faded within the spinner upon choosing a radio button that changes the contents of the spinner? I haven't done anything to the xml file and was only changing contents. I have it coded that it doesn't do this on the loading of the activity, only on the click of a radio button.

I can edit and add any code requested, I'm just not sure what to post or what the problem would be.

Edit:

My Radio Group code

```
guntype = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.category);

    guntype.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int pos = guntype.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));

            if (pos == 0){
                List<String> assaultrifles = new ArrayList<String>();
                assaultrifles.add("R-201 Carbine");
                assaultrifles.add("Hemlok BF-R");
                assaultrifles.add("G2A5");
                assaultrifles.add("V-47 Flatline");

                ArrayAdapter<String> assaultRifleAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,assaultrifles);
                assaultRifleAdapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner1.setAdapter(assaultRifleAdapt);
            }
```

My spinner code:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.assaultRifles, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
```

Comment: It will be better if you can paste few code snippets here. It will help us point out whats wrong.

Comment: @LoveForDroid edited with some code. Just didn't know where to start and didn't want to have a wall of code to search through if someone may have known what to look at.

Comment: By faded do you mean that the text is just a lighter color but everything else is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would affect it but you use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and then you use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. Try making them the same?